# Are there circumstances in which the current exponent for matrix multiplication can be beaten?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As food for a thought experiment, the following image displays two square matrices of dimension three, populated with elements that are distinct arrangements of arithmetic progressions. Their product matrix is included, **AB = C**.

[image]

Leaving aside the questions of whether we might ever be fortunate to encounter such a pairing, and whether we might wish to calculate their products, is there nonetheless a way to find the products "quickly"?

There is a subsidiary question that motivates this.  Is there a notion that it is sometimes useful to be able to calculate the sum of all of the elements in the product matrix akin to finding the trace of a matrix?

I believe that it is possible to demonstrate that there is a way to arrive at the products matrix relatively quickly for square matrices of any dimension where the elements are subject to similar constraints.  If this is essentially trivial or of limited practical value, then I should like to keep my powder dry.  It may be the case though, that perhaps there is some value in this to applications in mathematical physics or the like.

Comment: There is no trick hidden. One may write the explicit product and depending on the initial term $n$ of the arithmetic progression and the spacing of the sequence $d$ pull out the matrix $A\cdot n$ plus some term depending only on the spacing $d$ and the matrix $A$. If neither of these are given there is no potential to optimize as far as i can see.